# Why can't I convert object to Grease Pencil?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I want to convert my mesh object to grease pencil, and this may be a glitch but when I go to convert to--> it says convert to grease pencil from curve, not from mesh. I've done some research and whenever there is a tutorial on how to convert mesh to grease pencil everyone has the option to convert to grease pencil from curve/mesh, not just from a curve. Also, I have tried first converting mesh to curve and then converting curve to grease pencil but it doesn't work. Am I missing an add-on or is it something else?
[image]

I have attatched the .blend file here [image] and I have added a default cube with no converting done with it yet. Maybe there is something wrong in my settings.

UPDATE: I upgraded to the newest Blender (2.92) and it works perfect since there is only one option for convert to Grease Pencil. Still not sure why it doesn't work in version 2.9 for me though...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, even though it says mesh, it only converts it to curve no matter what. But, you could convert the mesh to curve. Then, you can convert the curve to a grease pencil. It's the same thing, the thing is there's just an extra step.

Comment: I've tried that with still no luck...I have attached the .blend file to the post so you can see my Blender and maybe there is something wrong with my settings.

Comment: You have posted it works fine in 2.92, so I guess the problem is solved. Also, I am probably guessing it is a bug, so no need to worry. I such amazing applications, a few bugs are common.